# GNU/Linux contest logging software?

Tags: software, linux, contest, logging

What contest logging software exists for the GNU/Linux operating system?

Comment: I started working on one, but most of the contest loggers are written in VB on Microsoft Access Databases.

Comment: http://meta.ham.stackexchange.com/questions/12/how-about-list-questions Voting to close as "too broad".

Answer (score 4):

I've used [CQRLOG](http://www.cqrlog.com/) which is built on MySQL but otherwise has many of the same features as other loggers and is fully customizable. If that's too much and you're looking for a simpler solution, [Xlog](http://xlog.nongnu.org/) is a barebones logger that can still interchange data with some of the Linux PSK and other digital mode software. Both support all the popular export formats, including adif and Cabrillo. The [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Amateur_Radio#Logging) has links to another 8 programs that might help, including [YFKtest](http://fkurz.net/ham/yfktest.html) or [TLF](http://home.iae.nl/users/reinc/TLF-0.2.html) if you're looking for a barebones console logger or [FDLog](http://www.fdlog.info/) with field-day-specific features and networking.

Comment: Another vote for CQRLOG.

Comment: Yep, but CQRLOG is rather a general logging program with all whistles and bells; not really a contest logging program.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to get a Linux logger is to use a windows logger under WINE Windows Program Loader, or something similar. I've done it before and it works fine, however it can cause problems on a slow computer.

Comment: I personally use N1MM on Win7 in the shack, my mobile/portable setup uses N1MM running under Wine on Linux Mint (Ubuntu) and it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

[Writelog](http://writelog.com/), [N1MM](http://n1mm.hamdocs.com) and [MMTTY](http://hamsoft.ca/pages/mmtty.php) all run under [Codeweavers CrossOver](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/crossover-linux/), the commercial version of Wine.

Apart from being much easier and convenient to use than Wine, my success rate with CrossOver is also a bit higher. Furthermore, I have no problem opening my wallet for this decently priced software in support of this company. (Disclosure: No conflict of interests.)